# AttributeError: 'Microgrid' object has no attribute 'add_generator' in pymgrid

Tags: python

I'm creating code with pymgrid but encounter an error and cant figure out how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```py
import pymgrid
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load hourly capacity data for the 4 PV systems and 8 loads from an excel file
capacity_data = pd.read_excel("capacity_data.xlsx")

# Initialize the arrays for storing the efficiency of self-sufficiency and the energy flows for each hour and each year
efficiency = np.zeros((8760, 20))
energy_flows = np.zeros((8760, 20))

# Create a pymgrid microgrid object and add the 4 PV systems and 8 loads
for year in range(20):
    microgrid = pymgrid.Microgrid(modules=[])
    for i in range(4):
        # Apply yearly degradation to the capacity of each PV system
        degradation = 1 - (year / 20) * 0.05
        pv_capacity = capacity_data["PV" + str(i)] * degradation
        
        # Convert the pv_capacity to a list-like object
        pv_capacity = pv_capacity.tolist()
        
        microgrid.add_generator("PV" + str(i), pv_capacity, pymgrid.GeneratorType.PV)
    for i in range(8):
        # Convert the load_capacity to a list-like object
        load_capacity = capacity_data["Load" + str(i)].tolist()
        
        microgrid.add_load("Load" + str(i), load_capacity)

    # Calculate the total energy generation and demand for each hour
    total_generation = microgrid.generation.sum(axis=1)
    total_demand = microgrid.demand.sum(axis=1)

    # Store the efficiency of self-sufficiency for each hour
    efficiency[:, year] = total_generation / total_demand

    # Store the energy flows for each hour
    energy_flows[:, year] = total_generation - total_demand

    # Plot the efficiency of self-sufficiency and the energy flows for each year
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(efficiency[:, year], label="Efficiency of Self-Sufficiency")
    plt.axhline(1, color="red", linestyle="--")
    plt.fill_between(efficiency[:, year].index, efficiency[:, year], 1, where=efficiency[:, year] < 1, color="gray", alpha=0.5)
    plt.xlabel("Hour")
    plt.ylabel("Efficiency")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(energy_flows[:, year], label="Energy Flows")
    plt.xlabel("Hour")
    plt.ylabel("Energy (kWh)")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I get an error in line 31:line 834, in **getattr**
return object.**getattribute**(self, item)

AttributeError: 'Microgrid' object has no attribute 'add_generator'

Comment: What makes you think a `Microgrid` object should have an `add_generator` attribute?

Comment: Not sure, im new with the library and learning how to use it, all help to fix the code is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://pymgrid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/microgrid.html) shows that such function is not implemented, hence your error. You can look there which functions are available to see if any suits your needs. `pymgrid` also has a `MicrogridGenerator` class, which you can see how it is used in the unit tests of the source code: [here](https://github.com/Total-RD/pymgrid/blob/9abd760b38596d6a524a38cd75c14b654b553159/tests/test_microgridgenerator.py).